# Drag map with limits

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a map (2d) which is about 5 times the size of the screen area. I can touch drag the map. However the user must only be able to drag it as far as the map is still showing. So the empty area outside map isn't showing.

So my question is: which of the two methods are best:

1) have colliders at the side of the screen and then put colliders on each side of the map. Then checking for collision and if so move the map so its collider does not touch the screen collider.

Or

2) check for the position of the map (i have an adjustable screen size according to device) and then stop the drag if it gets dragged further than visibility of screen. Using coordinates and math.

Will it take up more space (the ios/android) file if I use solution 1?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Shouldn't the colliders do this automatically (if set up correctly)? I don't think you need to write any extra code for that. 2. File size should not be your primary concern - runtime performance is.

Comment: So if I have an invisible collider square that takes up the screen area and colliders around the sides of my draggable map (and set it up correctly) it would be the best way? Thanks!

Comment: Both solutions work and will be fine in terms of performance or size. Just do whatever you think you can implement faster.